# Opensearch 3 node cluster's diskspace was upgraded from 500GB to 600GB. The copying of shards to new nodes became stuck

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch

AWS Opensearch 3 node cluster's diskspace was upgraded from 500GB to 600GB. Step 3 of 4: The copying of shards to new nodes became stuck. "Copying shards to new nodes - 48 of 52 done" is still the status after more than two days. I verified all of the parameters in monitoring (CPU, JVM, and storage) and they all look good. cluster status in green. What can we do now??

```
status:
$**curl -X GET 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/_cat/shards' | grep RELOCATING**        % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
xxxxxxxxxxx        1 r RELOCATING 8468110  69.5gb x.x.x.x Iron Maiden -> x.x.x.x dlzmg Douglock     
xxxxxxxxxxx        0 r RELOCATING 8461792  69.3gb x.x.x.x Iron Maiden -> x.x.x.x x6ElQ Count Abyss 
xxxxxxxxxxx        0 r RELOCATING 8734776  55.8gb x.x.x.x Iron Maiden -> x.x.x.x s6ElQ Count Abyss 
xxxxxxxxxxx        3 r RELOCATING   28558   7.2mb x.x.x.x Count Abyss -> x.x.x.x dlzmg Douglock
```

Comment: At this point I'd talk to AWS support, it's a managed service, let them fix it.

Comment: How many shards in total do you have? Could you share the cluster details?

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Did this finish after all? I'm in Copying shards to new nodes 12 of 202